# To find N Maximum indices of a numpy array whose corresponding values should greater than M in another array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have `3 Numpy arrays each of length 107952899`.

## Lets Say :

```
1. Time = [2.14579526e+08 2.14579626e+08 2.14579726e+08 ...1.10098692e+10  1.10098693e+10]
2. Speed = [0.66 0.66 0.66 .............0.06024864 0.06014756]

3. Brak_press = [0.3, 0.3, 0.3 .............. 0.3, 0.3]
```

## What it mean

Each index Value in Time corresponds to same index Value in Speed & Brake array.

```html
Time                Speed         Brake
2.14579526e+08      0.66          0.3
.
.
```

## Requirement

No 1 :I want to `find the indices in Speed array` whose `values` inside are `greater than 20`

No 2 : for those indices, `what will be values in Brake Array`

No 3 : Now i want to find the `Top N Maximum Value indices in Brake Array` & Store it another list/array

So finally if I take one indices from `Top N Maximum Indices` and use it in Brake & Speed array it must show..

```
Brake[idx] = valid Value & more importantly Speed [idx] = Value > than 20
```

## General Summary

Simply, What i needed is, to find the Maximum N Brake point indices whose corresponding speed Value should be greater than 20

## What i tried

```
    speed_20 = np.where(Speed > 20) # I got indices as tupple 
brake_values = Brake[speed_20]  # Found the Brake Values corresponds to speed_20 indices
```

After that i tried argsort/argpartition but none of result matches my requirement

## Request

I believe there will be a best method to do this..Kindly shed some light

(I converted the above `np arrays` to  `pandas df`, it works fine, due to memory concern i prefer to do using numpy operations)

Comment: What does 'top N maximum indices' mean? Can you maybe provide a smaller data sample where you explain more explicitly what you are after?

Comment: " i tried argsort/argpartition but none of result matches my requirement" always share what you've tried... especially since this seems a sensible approach...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are almost there. This should do what you want:

```
speed_20 = np.where(Speed > 20)[0]
sort = np.argsort(-Brake[speed_20])
result = speed_20[sort[:N]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is an option you can consider, using NumPy.

First create a multidimensional matrix (I changed the values so it's easier to follow):

```
Time =        [  2,   1,   5,   4,   3]
Speed =       [ 10,  20,  40,  30,  50]
Brak_press =  [0.1, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4, 0.2]

data = np.array([Time, Speed, Brak_press]).transpose()
```

So data are stored as:

```
print(data)
# [[ 2.  10.   0.1]
#  [ 1.  20.   0.3]
#  [ 5.  40.   0.5]
#  [ 4.  30.   0.4]
#  [ 3.  50.   0.2]]
```

To extract speed greater than 20:

```
data[data[:,1] > 20]
# [[ 5.  40.   0.5]
#  [ 4.  30.   0.4]
#  [ 3.  50.   0.2]]
```

To get the n greatest Brak_press:

```
n = 2
data[data[:,2].argsort()[::-1][:n]]
# [[ 5.  40.   0.5]
#  [ 4.  30.   0.4]]
```

Comment: Also, Can i add another condition in speed extraction line, like `data[data[:,1] > 20 & data[:,2] > 40]´ which tells brake value above 40. Like the way we do it in pandas ???
I tried but results in TypeError. Is there is any other method to do the above function ?

Comment: It's a matrix. For multiple condition enclose in parentheses: `data[(data[:,1] > 20) & (data[:,2] <= 0.4)]`

Comment: You could also set column names `time = data[:,0]` etc. so the code is easier to read.

Comment: Thank you ..
I have another query related to indices of the example multi D array you mentioned.After extracting the speed Value greater than 20 & brake Value greater than 30 i will get a matrix say 1*3 i.e [Time Speed Brake]. Now if i want to know the original index of this row how can i find it ??? Since i want to access the values of original array with this indices

Comment: You could look inside the original array as suggested by the answer you choosed. Or include the index as fourth column: `data = np.array([Time, Speed, Brak_press, range(len(Time))]).transpose()`

Comment: Also when i execute this function  data1 = data1 [data1 [:, Brake].argsort()[::-1][: N].]
This results in IndexError : arrays used as indices must be Integers (or boolean) type..What is the reason ?